# SSE2 intrinsics - find max of two unsigned short vectors

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd

I want to find max of two vectors containing 8 x 16 bit unsigned int elements.

```
__m128i vi_A= _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(&pSrc[0])); // 8 16-Bit Elements
__m128i vi_B= _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(&pSrc1[0])); // 8 16-Bit Elements
__m128i vi_Max = _mm_max_epi16(vi_A,vi_B);  //<-- Error
```

But this `_mm_max_epi16` is a signed int comparison and this causes overflow.
So I tried to use the unsigned version of it by using SSE4.1 intrinsic

```
vi_Max = _mm_max_epu16(vi_A,vi_B);
```

but I'm not allowed to use SSE4.1 intrinsics. So what is the efficient way to find the max of these elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One (somewhat inefficient) way of doing it is to offset the input values by 0x8000 and then add this offset back to the result, e.g.:

```
#ifndef __SSE4_1__
inline __m128i _mm_max_epu16(const __m128i v0, const __m128i v1)
{
    return _mm_add_epi16(
               _mm_max_epi16(
                   _mm_sub_epi16(v0, _mm_set1_epi16(0x8000)),
                   _mm_sub_epi16(v1, _mm_set1_epi16(0x8000))),
               _mm_set1_epi16(0x8000));
}
#endif
```

With gcc or clang this generates one load instruction for the constant and four arithmetic instructions.

---

Note that you can use `_mm_xor_si128` in place of `_mm_add_epi16`/`_mm_sub_epi16`, which is arguably clearer in intent, and may give better performance on your target architecture:

```
#ifndef __SSE4_1__
inline __m128i _mm_max_epu16(const __m128i v0, const __m128i v1)
{
    return _mm_xor_si128(
               _mm_max_epi16(
                   _mm_xor_si128(v0, _mm_set1_epi16(0x8000)),
                   _mm_xor_si128(v1, _mm_set1_epi16(0x8000))),
               _mm_set1_epi16(0x8000));
}
#endif
```

Comment: Wow Thank you for your quick Answer! It worked like charm!

Comment: XORing is very likely faster, but even more importantly, it eliminates the possibility of overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray what overflow? adding/subtracting/xoring a 16bit int with 0x8000 are all exactly equivalent, with no edge cases

Comment: @CodyGray: `_mm_xor_si128` *may* be faster on newer CPUs (0.33 throughput versus 0.5 for `_mm_add_epi16`/`_mm_sub_epi16 ` on Intel Nehalem/Westmere/SB/IB/Haswell), but the OP is evidently using an older architecture, so that may not be the case. As always, it's best to benchmark, but my guess is that there won't be a significant difference. As noted above, overflow is not an issue. Also note that clang converts the above to use `_mm_xor_si128` during code generation, which is pretty cool.

Comment: Well, there is a possibility for overflowing the range of a signed 16-bit int, but I suppose the claim is it's not a problem because `paddw` has explicitly well-defined wrap-around semantics in the case of overflow. But I still personally find XOR clearer to understand. Maybe that's just a silly subjective preference, though. XOR is also generally able to run on more execution units than ADD/SUB is, which would apply to older architectures as well. That is very cool that Clang does the conversion, though.

Comment: @CodyGray: yes, on reflection I think using XOR might be clearer, and since it's at least as efficient as using subtract/add, then maybe it's a better solution overall. I'll update the answer shortly...